# How to make a Silverlight app take up the entire browser width/height?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a page that is just an ASP-hosted Silverlight 4 object. I would like it to take up the full width and height of the browser, but it is not - it is too small, in a corner. Where can I adjust this?

I'm new to Silverlight. Thanks for the help.

**Edit:** Here is the .xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ExpenseCalc_SilverLight.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
        <Rectangle Height="441" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-21,-14,0,0" Name="rectangle1" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="583" Fill="#FFA86E6E" Opacity="1" />
        <TextBlock Height="114" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,14,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="Current Expenses" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="424" FontSize="28" />

        <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="78" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,60,0,0" Name="CurrentExpensesGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="494" />

        <TextBlock FontSize="15" Height="114" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,158,0,0" Name="textBlock2" Text="Add New" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="424" />
        <sdk:Label Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,187,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48" Content="Name" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,205,0,0" Name="NameTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74" />
        <sdk:Label Content="Date" Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="97,187,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48" />
        <sdk:Label Content="Cost" Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="203,187,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48" />
        <sdk:Label Content="Who paid" Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="257,187,0,0" Name="label4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" />

        <TextBox Text="{Binding Cost, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="203,205,0,0" Name="CostTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48" />

        <sdk:Label Content="Who owes" Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="337,187,0,0" Name="label5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" />
        <sdk:AutoCompleteBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="337,205,0,0" Name="WhoOwesInput" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74" ValueMemberBinding="{Binding}" LostFocus="WhoOwesInput_LostFocus" />
        <sdk:Label Content="Receipt" Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="417,187,0,0" Name="label6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" />
        <Button Content="Add" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="337,154,0,0" Name="AddButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" FontSize="15" Click="AddButton_Click" />
        <sdk:DatePicker Text="{Binding Date, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="97,205,0,0" Name="datePicker1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" />
        <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="257,205,0,0" Name="WhoPaidComboBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74" />
        <ListBox Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="337,232,0,0" Name="WhoOwesListBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74" KeyDown="WhoOwesListBox_KeyDown" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="418,205,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a SL application and choose to create a Web Applicatio, the VS template creates a .html file that does exactly what you are looking for. The key parts are the following

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#silverlightControlHost {
    height: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
```

And in the `<form>` the control is wrapped in a `<div id="silverlightControlHost">` element.

I would suggest you create a quick test app, select the option to create a hosting web application and then take the markup from there.

Comment: That CSS was generated for me, but I'm still having this issue. Is it possibly something in my SL .xaml?

Comment: Is it the SL host that is small or the markup in the host. A quick way to check is to rignt click in the area you expect the host control to be and see if you get the standard SL pop up menu or the web browser popup menu.

Comment: I get the SL pop up menu. So the contents of my app is what's too small.

Comment: @Rosarch, can you share some of the XAML for the root user control. Then we can see where the problem is. It is possible that you have a Width/Height set on the control which is fixing the size of the control.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your usercontrols are hardcoded some size